# CakePHP 3 output .ctp template as CSV file

Tags: php, csv, cakephp

In CakePHP 3.5.13 I have a Controller action as follows:

```
class ReportController extends AppController
{
    public function download($id, $format)
    {

    }
}
```

What I want to do is pass parameters for a report ID and format (e.g. XLSX, CSV) to the `download` function, e.g. `/report/download/123/csv` would obtain data for report 123 and output it as a CSV.

I have all the data required for my report in an array, `$data`. I want to create separate templates (.ctp files) to format my data in each of the desired formats, and then have the `download()` function send them to the browser for download.

So I adapted my function as follows:

```
public function download($id, $format)
{
    $data = // ... Model data in array format

    $filename = '123'; // filename for the download

    switch ($format):
        case 'csv':
            header('Content-type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.csv"');

            $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
            $this->set('data', $data);
            $this->render('download_csv');
        break;
    endswitch;
}
```

This correctly renders a template I have from `Template/Report/download_csv.ctp`. It is also correctly rendered in the ajax layout (`$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');` means it uses `Template/Layout/ajax.ctp` and therefore doesn't contain any "wrapper" HTML).

When visiting `/report/download/123/csv` the browser sends a file called `123.csv` with the data I have requested. However, the Response type is `text/html` and not `text/csv` as specified in my Controller action.

This is causing the file contents to be malformed - it's treating it like HTML instead of CSV. For example if I have the following in my `download_csv.ctp` template:

```
"Field 1", "123\n456",
"Field 2", "789"
```

It is being output literally as shown here in Excel:

[image]

I'm guessing this problem is due to the fact the Response is actually HTML and not CSV, but I'm not sure.

My question is whether it's possible to use .ctp files in this way and have them output as downloads to the browser in a specified format?

I know there are other things that can be done with Routing and URL extensions but this question doesn't concern those. I don't want to use Plugins/extensions either. I want to know if it's possible to use `$this->render()` and have Cake render a template which is sent to the browser for download in the requested format?

Comment: I agree with below, that https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview should be used here, it is way cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `render()` will simply render the given template and populate the response body with the rendered data, irrespectively of what is going to happen with the reponse, and with which content type it is being sent - so the answer is yes, you can render templates and serve them as downloads.

Excel not importing the data as you expect, most likely doesn't have anything to do with CakePHP, because the CSV file doesn't contain any content type information. Maybe you chose the wrong text qualifier (`"`) when importing the file.

That being said, controllers shouldn't output data, that includes headers! Outputting data in a controller can lead to all kinds of problems, from the data not being recognized in the test environment, to headers not being able to be sent, and even data being cut off. Instead, use the proper response object methods to prepare a download response accordingly, in your case you're looking for `withType()` and `withDownload()`, like:

```
case 'csv':
    $this->response = $this->response->withType('csv');
    $this->response = $this->response->withDownload($filename. '.csv');

    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->render('download_csv');
break;
```

This will add proper `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers.

See also:

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#response)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response > Dealing with Content Types](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response > Sending a String as File](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file)**